# How to make GDB print out all values in hexadecimal mode?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

By default, GDB always prints/displays all variables / arguments in base 10.

Is there any way to ask GDB to always use base 16 while printing anything (and turn back to default settings when I don't need that)?

I know that it can be printed by supplying the `/x` argument to print/display, but I don't want to do it every time.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`set output-radix 16` (and `set output-radix 10` to switch it back).

Comment: It too bad this does not work in practice... [How do I force GDB to print in base 16?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44015338/608639)

Comment: Works for me, with `bt full`. So maybe it doesn't _always_ work (as described in the linked question), but sometimes it works really well.

Comment: Now open in the GDB Bugzilla: [Issue 23390, GDB does not honor 'set output-radix 16'; it displays in octal](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23390). I could not take it anymore. Man I loathe working with GDB. I cringe when it is the only debugger available.

Comment: Works for me. gdb --version: 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7_4.1

Comment: Works, for me except inside strings. I'm working with UTF/ISO conversions so would be really helpful to have "unknown" chars displayed in hex instead of octal.

Comment: @jww: I got octal values like `\243\300` when printing arrays. To fix this, `p/x *my_arr@arr_len` printed the variable's values in hex. `p/z` adds leading zeros if necessary, e.g., 0x8 becomes 0x08. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528732/gdb-print-all-values-in-char-array).

Answer (score 0):

In my machine, `set output-radix 10` doesn't work, but `set output-radix 0xA` works.

Comment: What does `show input-radix` tell you?