# Print variables in hexadecimal or decimal format

Tags: gdb

Currently, when I print the value of a variable `v` in GDB (`print v`) I get an integer.

Is it possible to have GDB print such integer variables in hexadecimal or binary?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Sure it is. Try these:

```
# Hexadecimal
p/x variable

# Binary
p/t variable
```

See [output formats](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_54.html).

Comment: if you are using DDD(data display debuger, a GUI wrapper for a debugger like GDB), you can use the hex format also in graphic display by doing  `graph disp /x val1`. Beware you should put space before `/x`. otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: and to set the default output radix setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618670/how-to-make-gdb-print-out-all-values-in-hexadecimal-mode

Comment: To show the values of an [array](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html) in hex, use `p/x *my_arr@arr_len`.