# Gdb shows uint8 buffers as octal. How can I make it show hexadecimal instead?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm doing some debugging with networking. We use a lot of byte strings. Maybe it's not kosher, but when looking directly at the unfiltered bytes in gdb, they get represented like /byte in octal/byte in octal/byte in octal. I prefer to think about that stuff in hex since most of our data fully uses the byte. Is there anyway to make gdb use hexadecimal instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618670/how-to-make-gdb-print-out-all-values-in-hexadecimal-mode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671820/gdb-print-variables-in-hex-or-decimal-format

Comment: Do you mean octal? Octet is another word for byte.

Comment: That doesn't work for pointer values: just normal consts.