# 'backtrace full' command, output in HEX

Tags: debugging, gdb

In GDB, doing `backtrace full` will print all local variables, together with their values, in decimal.

Is there a way to print the local variable values in HEX instead of decimal? (I want something similar to `print/x myVar`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make gdb print out all values in hexadecimal mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618670/how-to-make-gdb-print-out-all-values-in-hexadecimal-mode)

Comment: set output-radix 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `output-radix`, documented [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Numbers).