# GNU GDB: customize watchpoint output format

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

Every time a watchpoint is modified GDB will print the old value and the new value. However, sometimes I don't want to print the value in the default decimal integer format: for instance, if I'm watching `*(unsigned*)$ebp` to debug a possible stack overflow (wow, SO...), the value is nonsense unless displayed in hexadecimal format (like `p/x` when printing something).

Is it possible to set the display format for a particular watchpoint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the display format for a particular watchpoint?

If you want the watchpoint to print in hex, set it as watch of a pointer, e.g.

```
watch *(char**)$ebp     or
watch *(void**)$ebp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set output-radix 16
```

Please refer to this answer [How to make gdb print out all values in hexadecimal mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618686/5409274)

You can set all types of prints happening due to gdb (may it be because of breakpoints, watchpoints, or your custom prints) will have hex-format.